# factory_boy DjangoModelFactory not creating Model entries for testing

Tags: python, django-testing, factory-boy

I am trying to test my django app using factory_boy to setup the model instances.

I have the following factories setup for certain Django models.

```
class StudyFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Study

    group = SubFactory(GroupFactory)

@create_attrs(values)
class SomeFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel

    study = SubFactory(StudyFactory)
    some_attr = "some attribute"


@create_attrs(values)
class AnotherFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = AnotherModel

    study = SubFactory(StudyFactory)
```

I am trying to run a test with the following setup and teardown:

```
class SomeTests(TestCase):
    fixtures = ["users.json"]

    def setUp(self):
        self.study = StudyFactory()
        self.some = SomeFactory(study=self.study)
        self.another = AnotherFactory(study=self.study)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.study.delete()
        self.some.delete()
        self.another.delete()
```

First, this throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'SomeFactory' has no attribute 'delete'
```

So I check the detail on `self.study`:

```
isinstance(self.study, Study)
>>> True
Study.objects.all()
>>> <QuerySet [<Study: 2014-02-14>]>   # queryset contains values
self.study.group.id
>>> 2
```

Factory seems to create a proper instance of Study for use in the tests. But when I look at the details for `self.some`:

```
isinstance(self.some, SomeModel)
>>> False   # not SomeModel
type(self.some)
>>> FactoryMetaClass
Some.objects.all()
>>> <QuerySet []>   # empty queryset
self.some.some_attr
>>> "some attribute"  # the attribute can still be called!
self.some.study.group.id
>>> AttributeError: 'SubFactory' object has no attribute 'id' # fails even though self.study.group.id did not
```

So StudyFactory creates a usable Django object, while SomeFactory does not, instead creating a FactoryMetaClass.

The reason for the question is: I need to be able to perform some functions on the SomeFactory() instance and they do not work if I cannot generate querysets from SomeModel after calling SomeFactory().

I am wondering if this results from the decorator I use on SomeFactory, or if its because of the SubFactory relationship between the two, or if there is some other effect I do not understand.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please provide your `create_attrs` decorator